# JavaFX - Flexible paginated grid - Basis:GridPane, FlowPane or TilePane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

If you were to program a custom control, that "users" of that class could specify the CellFactory for:

**What class would you use as a basis and how would you go about it?**

[Here is a picture of what it might look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT7J3.png)

---

My thoughts so far:

Specifying a number of rows and columns for this control would make the user have more direct control over what the control will look like in the end. That would work better with a GridPane

Everything else I can think of (alignment, spacing, calc, pref, min, max width) can be done with all three of the base controls. Come to think of it even the specific rows and columns could be done with calculations with the other base classes. Might just be a little harder though.

Since I would want every cell to be the same size, TilePane is out. But does it even make sense to have this restriction?

---

**What would you choose and why?**

**What would you want a control like this to support / how should it behave?**

(Esp. regarding alignment, width calculations and such, but other thoughts are more then welcome, too!)

---

Last but not least: Is this question better for another stackexchange site? If so I can remove this one and ask there. :)

Comment: Hmm... How about [`GridView`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) from ControlsFX ?

Comment: I like the pagination style, easier to find things if you know what you are looking for, then a scrollable implementation imo. But looking at the implementation of GridView is defiantly a good idea! Will do that in addition to what people come up here :D

Comment: "Since I would want every cell to be the same size, `TilePane` is out". Isn't that exactly what `TilePane` does?

Comment: Maybe worded incorrectly. I thought tile pane lays out the cells according to the biggest one, but i want the to somehow make sure, that each cell has the same size, then a TilePane's uniqueness over FloatPane would not be used at all. But as I'm writing this I realise, that maybe it does not make sense to impose this restriction.

Comment: How do I do a cross post on stackexchange? Just post it there too and note in both posts that I cross-posted?

Comment: It's hard to word this question, since I can think of implementations using any of those base classes. I just do not want to choose and find out later that the other base class would have made way more sense. Maybe a more discussion based site would fit this question better? Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Of course @jewelsea. Sorry for that lazy question :( will look for that then.

Comment: @jewelsea you gave some awesome feedback, that doesn't answer the wording of the question, but the spirit. Going to the control specifications standard, then posting what i came up with in ux.stackexchange.com and then (if I haven't figured the best way to do it by then) coming back here with the exact specs is what I'm going to do. If you want to post your thoughts as an answer, I'd gladly accept :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not directly answering your question, I will post some additional information here which may be helpful for you.

- Unfortunately StackExchange sites are not good for discussions, you could try the [ControlsFX google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/controlsfx-dev), though I don't really know how helpful that will be for you.
- Check out the [existing user experience specifications](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/ColorPicker+User+Experience+Documentation) for standard JavaFX controls, perhaps try creating one of these before you write your control, maybe post the specification to ux.stackexchange for feedback (if that is appropriate based upon ux.stackechange posting policies, which can be found at
  [ux.stackexchange.com/help](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help)).
- You might find this [grid pane based color chooser code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2030464) helpful for you.
- ControlsFX has a [GridView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) which you should consider.